# How can I make the images in a row

Tags: html, css, image, web

Hey I'm programming for the first time a Website and I have a little problem. The Problem is that I cant make the images in a row.

How it should be:

[image: desired]

How it is:

[image: actual]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(35, 50, 64);
  color: white;
}

.social-images {
  text-align: left;
}

#logo-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2200px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}

#top {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: -20px;
}

#navigation a {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

#navigation a:hover {
  color: rgb(90, 176, 247);
}

#image img {
  >width: 100%;
  >margin-top: 16px;
  >margin-bottom: 16px;
  >height: auto;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  color: grey;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Leon Kannenberg</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top">
    <div id="logo-name">Leon Kannenberg</div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <a href="#top">Startseite</a>
      <a href="#about-us">Über mich</a>
      <a href="#projects">Projekte</a> <a href="#social">Social</a>
      <a href="#contacts">Kontakt</a>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="Ein sehr schönes Bild">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <section id="main">
      <section id="about-us"></section>
      <h2>Über mich</h2>
      <p>
        Hallo! Mein Name ist Leon Kannenberg. Ich bin 18 Jahre alt und ein Inforamtik interessierter Mensch. Dementsprechend habe ich diese Website komplett alleine Programmiert. Die Website soll meine Begeisterung für die Inforamtikwelt wiederspiegeln. Ich habe
        bereits mehrere Projekte in bearbeitung die bald bei dem Gleichnamigen Berreich reingestellt werden. Hoffentlich gefällt dir meine Website und ich wünsche dir hier noch viel Spaß drauf!
      </p>
      <section id="projects"></section>
      <h2>Projekte</h2>
      <p>
        Coming Soon!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="social"></section>
    <h2>Social</h2>
    <p>
      <div class="social-images">
        <img class="img-instagram" src="instagram.png" width="500" height="400" alt="Instagram von Leon Kannenberg" />
        <img class="img-facebook" src="facebook.png" width="500" height="400" alt="Facebook von Leon Kannenberg" />
        <img class="img-twitter" src="twitter.png" width="500" height="400" alt="Twitter von Leon Kannenberg" />
      </div>
    </p>
    <section id="contacts"></section>
    <h2>Kontakt</h2>
    <p>
      Kontakt page Coming Soon!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Copyright 2021 | Leon Kannenberg
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, `<` is for adding quotations, you can use the `{ }` icon to insert code blocks

Comment: Also `<div>` tags are not allowed inside `<p>` tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.social-images{
  display: flex;
}
```

`display: inline-block` would also work. Visit [CSS - Display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for more info.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(35, 50, 64);
  color: white;
}

.social-images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: left;
}

#logo-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2200px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}

#top {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: -20px;
}

#navigation a {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}

#navigation a:hover {
  color: rgb(90, 176, 247);
}

#image img {
  >width: 100%;
  >margin-top: 16px;
  >margin-bottom: 16px;
  >height: auto;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  color: grey;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Leon Kannenberg</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top">
    <div id="logo-name">Leon Kannenberg</div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <a href="#top">Startseite</a>
      <a href="#about-us">Über mich</a>
      <a href="#projects">Projekte</a> <a href="#social">Social</a>
      <a href="#contacts">Kontakt</a>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="Ein sehr schönes Bild">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <section id="main">
      <section id="about-us"></section>
      <h2>Über mich</h2>
      <p>
        Hallo! Mein Name ist Leon Kannenberg. Ich bin 18 Jahre alt und ein Inforamtik interessierter Mensch. Dementsprechend habe ich diese Website komplett alleine Programmiert. Die Website soll meine Begeisterung für die Inforamtikwelt wiederspiegeln. Ich habe
        bereits mehrere Projekte in bearbeitung die bald bei dem Gleichnamigen Berreich reingestellt werden. Hoffentlich gefällt dir meine Website und ich wünsche dir hier noch viel Spaß drauf!
      </p>
      <section id="projects"></section>
      <h2>Projekte</h2>
      <p>
        Coming Soon!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="social"></section>
    <h2>Social</h2>
    <p>
      <div class="social-images">
        <img class="img-instagram" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="500" height="400" alt="Instagram von Leon Kannenberg" />
        <img class="img-facebook" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="500" height="400" alt="Facebook von Leon Kannenberg" />
        <img class="img-twitter" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="500" height="400" alt="Twitter von Leon Kannenberg" />
      </div>
    </p>
    <section id="contacts"></section>
    <h2>Kontakt</h2>
    <p>
      Kontakt page Coming Soon!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Copyright 2021 | Leon Kannenberg
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: okay its like pretty much to the right so how can i center it and make some space between the images?

Comment: try adding `justify-content: space-between` to the above. You can see all possible values and illustrations at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Added an example in the answer. The images are already centred on the page as far as I fan see. You can also create spacing using simple `margin`

Comment: it isnt its loke like this: https://imgur.com/a/1phF10Q

Comment: Your `#main { max-width: 800px;` doesn't allow it to have enough width. Either make images smaller, or make content width bigger.

Answer (score 0):

parent container

```css
display: flex;
```

img containers

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: nowrap; /* you can use wrap in case you want it to overflow*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Study flexbox or grid in css for example on w3 schools: 
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp 
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp